# Assign a List object to another List in c#

Tags: c#, list, object

I have following classes:

```
public class ProviderQualification
{
    public List<ProviderDetail> ProviderDetails { get; set; }
}
public class ProviderDetail
{
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public string ServiceableOffers { get; set; }
}
public class ProviderQualificationTimeViewModel
{
    public List<ProviderQualificationDetail> ProviderQualificationDetails { get; set; }
}
public class ProviderQualificationDetail
{
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public string TotalServiceableOffers { get; set; }
}
```

I have `ProviderQualification` object populated with `List<ProviderDetail>`.

```
ProviderQualification providerQualification = reporting.GetProviderQualification();
```

Now I want to copy this list to my `List<ProviderQualificationDetail>`. How would I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to transform a `List<ProviderDetail>` into a `List<ProviderQualificationDetail>` just by creating new instance of `ProviderQualificationDetail>` an copying the properties? You should look at LINQ, and in particular the `Select` and `ToList` methods.

Comment: How to get `TotalServiceableOffers`  from `ServiceableOffers`  ? Concatenate with some delimiter ? Group by ProviderName ? Or Is it the same value with different property name ?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes. I want to assign `List<ProviderDetail>`  to `List<ProviderQualificationDetail>`. Is it possible?

Comment: @user3185569 same value with different property name

Comment: Just assigning it? No, absolutely not. Creating a new list, and populating it by converting each element of the old list? Yes.

Comment: @zaria. Do you want to select distinct ProviderName and total ServiceableOffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mapping to get from `ProviderDetail` to `ProviderQualificationDetail`. For example, if you just want to copy over those values, you can just write it inline like this:

```
ProviderQualification providerQualification = reporting.GetProviderQualification();

var items = providerQualification.ProviderDetails
            .Select(detail => new ProviderQualificationDetail
                {
                    ProviderName = detail.ProviderName,
                    TotalServiceableOffers = detail.ServiceableOffers
                })
            .ToList();

var viewModel = new ProviderQualificationTimeViewModel
{
    ProviderQualificationDetails = items
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Linq:

```
List<ProviderQualificationDetail> result = 
         providerQualification.ProviderDetails.Select(
                         q => new ProviderQualificationDetail() 
                                   { 
                                       ProviderName  = q.ProviderName, 
                                       TotalServiceableOffers = q.ServiceableOffers 
                                   }).ToList();
```

Using `Select` you project each element in `ProviderDetails` into a new element of type `ProviderQualificationDetail` and then Enumerate that into a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> Enumerable.Select< TSource, TResult > Method (IEnumerable< TSource >, Func< TSource, TResult >)

For example

```
List<ProviderQualificationDetail> list = 
providerQualification.ProviderDetails
.Select(x => new ProviderQualificationDetail(){
    ProviderName = x.ProviderName,
    TotalServiceableOffers = x.ServiceableOffers
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, @zaria want to select distinct `ProviderName` and total `ServiceableOffers`. If she has `ProviderQualification` class why she wants  to bind to `ProviderQualificationDetail`?

```
 List<ProviderQualificationDetail> list=providerQualification.ProviderDetails.GroupBy(x => x.ProviderName)
                                          .Select(x=>new ProviderQualificationDetail{
                                                   ProviderName =x.Key,
                                                   TotalServiceableOffers=Sum(y=>y.ServiceableOffers) 
                                           }).ToList();
```